# To count quickly until first match and stop in megastring

Tags: unix, count

I want to count number of characters until the pattern `030` in megarow (do not read data forward from that point) such that you do not read the whole megarow in in memory. 
It should return 28.

Megastring Data

```
48000000fe5a1eda480000000d00030001000000cd010000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000001000000ffffffff57ea5e55ff640c00585e0000fe5a1eda480000000d00030007000000cd010000010000000000000002000000000000800000000000000000000000
```

My initial idea was to split at first instance of `030` but I did not succeed with this. 
I am also not familiar with split command's capability to read only until the end of the pattern.

How can you count quickly until the first match?

Comment: `awk '{print index($0, "030")-1}' file` But I am not sure if it's good enough for you.

Comment: I thought about using awk too but I think the string is going to be so large that you don't want to read the whole string in.

Comment: @David I am not sure if awk does read in a whole line. It could simply open the file and search for the pattern and just move the file pointer and subtract from the initial position. It depends on the specific awk implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your megarow is in a file named megarow_file you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=megarow_file
SEARCH_STRING="030"

comp_string=""

while IFS= read -r -n1 char
do
    char_count=`expr $char_count + 1`
    comp_string="${comp_string}${char}"

    comp_string_length=${#comp_string}

    if [ $comp_string_length -eq 3 ]; then
       # echo comparing value $comp_string
       if [ $comp_string = $SEARCH_STRING ]; then
           # echo match
           break
       fi
    fi

    if [ $comp_string_length -gt 3 ]; then
        # echo its bigger than 3, strip 1st char
        comp_string="${comp_string:1:3}"
        # echo comparing value $comp_string
        if [ $comp_string = $SEARCH_STRING ]; then
            # echo match
            break
        fi
    fi

done < "$INPUT"

count_up_to_comp_string=`expr $char_count - ${#SEARCH_STRING}`
echo "Length up to ${SEARCH_STRING} was ${count_up_to_comp_string} characters"
```

Comment: `030` case works. Choose `SEARCH_STRING="0300"` giving `Length up to 0300 was 243 characters` i.e. the length of the whole string. It should be 33 so it misses the both `0300` matches. The `comp_string` with slicing may be the source of the bug.

Comment: @Masi - the script above will only work with a search string of 3 characters, it would need modification to make it more generic and support search strings of a different length

Answer (score 0):

Comparing GNU awk and BSD AWK initiated by BlueMoon's comment

```
$ time cat megaRow | awk '{print index($0, "fafafafa")-1}'
48584    
real    1m13.489s
user    1m11.608s
sys 0m4.685s

$ time cat megaRow | gawk '{print index($0, "fafafafa")-1}'
48584    
real    1m12.792s
user    1m8.845s
sys 0m4.933s
```

where GNU AWK little faster but not enough significantly, because within uncertainty.

Comment: You can avoid the pipe (which is another process -- needless) and redirect to a file (console printing is typically slow): `awk '{print index($0, "fafafafa")-1}' megaRow >outFile` and compare the awk's and David's plain bash version.